# Stale element reference Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium, firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I tried to implement a test suite using selenium.

While writing the automated script, the driver is able to enter the data using xpath. In the result I can see the value entered into the text box, but while saving the page throws error that data is not entered in to the column(Stale element Exception).

To solve this, I tried to move the focus out and get back to the column and enter the data again. Still I am getting the same kind of error.

Error Message:

> Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it
>   was looked up For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html Build
>   info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30
>   03:03:16' System info: host: 'HQ04HQQTP006', ip: '10.10.220.164',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_66' Driver info: driver.version: unknown Command duration or
>   timeout: 8.17 seconds For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html Build
>   info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30
>   11:02:44' System info: host: 'HQ-GRID-001', ip: '10.10.1.206',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_65' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, version=40.0.3, platform=WINDOWS,
>   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true,
>   webdriver.remote.sessionid=b95bec47-70a6-4c88-bbc0-e38c9d56aff0,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   b95bec47-70a6-4c88-bbc0-e38c9d56aff0

Please let me know if I am not clear in the question, I will try to explain it more.

[image]

Comment: can you add your code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two tips for you to try here:

1. After doing sendKeys do `sendKeys(Keys.TAB)` on same element or click some other text box. The point of doing this here is There might be some fields that update data after you enter something into other field. Example : Actual column.
2. Now after this is done and you see the data entered correctly, you need to give some time to your save button in case if it was disabled initially. In this case, use:
   `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);`

   `WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.YOUR LOCATOR));`

Here I would recommend that you mention the locator and Not a previously identified element, since refreshing etc. may corrupt previously identified elements.